# MkvToolNix: Bat file / Batch file to mux pairs of videos together

Tags: batch-file, mkv, muxer

Struggling for some time in that problem. I have a list of videos going this way, by pairs :

magic.mkv
magic-1.mkv

food.mkv
food-2.mkv

wedding.mkv
wedding-3.mkv

etc.

Each video has its pair, and the pair has a number that is incrementing every time. I want to mux each pair together. And for each pair : First video (without the numbers) keep everything except for chapters, Second video (with the incrementing number) to keep all subtitles only.

Now I know how to select tracks and so on, what I don't know, is how to make this .bat file mux those pairs, whiches are all in the same folder. (I know I could put each pair in a different folder, but I have more than 700 files so first I would like to see if there is a way to do this with code)

Opened to any suggestion (I'm not very tech saavy please be specific).

Thank you in advance.

Tried that, and it crashed (`"error the file cannont be opened for reading" - open file error`) :

```bash
for %%a & for %%a-1 in (*.mkv) do "\\\\\\MKV Tool Nix\mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "tada\%%~a" --default-track "5:yes" --track-order 1:0,1:1,1:2,1:3,0:4,0:5,0:6,0:7,0:8,0:9,0:10 "%%~a"
```

Tried that, and it crashed (`"error the file cannont be opened for reading" - open file error`) :

```bash
for %%a in (*.mkv) do "C:\\MKV Tool Nix\mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "tada\%%~a" '(' %%~na-1%%~xa ')' --default-track "5:yes" --track-order 1:0,1:1,1:2,1:3,0:4,0:5,0:6,0:7,0:8,0:9,0:10 "%%~a"
```

Tried that, and it does not crash, but it looks for the second video like that : `videoone.mkv-1`, as opposed to `videoone-1.mkv`. It means that `%%a` will look for the full name including the specified extension, so probably `%%a` is not the right thing to use since I need to specify a file name, then the extension :

```bash
for %%a in (*.mkv) do "C:\\MKV Tool Nix\mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "tada\%%~a" '(' %%a %%a-1 ')' --default-track "5:yes" --track-order 1:0,1:1,1:2,1:3,0:4,0:5,0:6,0:7,0:8,0:9,0:10 "%%~a"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following example script help you out?

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For %%G In (
    *-1*.mkv
    *-2*.mkv
    *-3*.mkv
    *-4*.mkv
    *-5*.mkv
    *-6*.mkv
    *-7*.mkv
    *-8*.mkv
    *-9*.mkv
) Do (
    Set "filebasename=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "filebasename=!filebasename:.=?!"
    For %%H In ("!filebasename:-=.!") Do (
        EndLocal
        Set "pairedfilebasename=%%~nH"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Set "pairedfilebasename=!pairedfilebasename:.=-!"
        For %%I In ("!pairedfilebasename:?=.!") Do (
            EndLocal
            If Exist "%%~I%%~xG" (
                Echo matching suffixed filename to "%%~I%%~xG" is "%%~G"
            )
        )
    )
)

Pause
```

All you should need to do, if it works for you, is change the `Echo` command line to your particular `mkvmerge.exe` command line, *remembering that `"%%~I%%~xG"` is the non suffixed filename and `"%%G"` is the suffixed one*.

Depending upon the makeup of your specific filenames you may wish to change:

```bash
    *-1*.mkv
    *-2*.mkv
    *-3*.mkv
    *-4*.mkv
    *-5*.mkv
    *-6*.mkv
    *-7*.mkv
    *-8*.mkv
    *-9*.mkv
```

to:

```bash
    *-*0.mkv
    *-*1.mkv
    *-*2.mkv
    *-*3.mkv
    *-*4.mkv
    *-*5.mkv
    *-*6.mkv
    *-*7.mkv
    *-*8.mkv
    *-*9.mkv
```

If your filenames are even more complex, you may be better advised to change to outer `For` loop to a `For /F` loop using the `Dir` command piped to `findstr.exe` filtering using something like `/IR "\-[123456789][0123456789]*\.mkv$"`.

Comment: Hi Compo, thank you very much for the feedback. I'm struggling to understand where to insert the mkvmerge path, the output path, and the specific track selections. I have modified it that way : https://codefile.io/f/WuFVh7UZV2

But it returns that the -o (output) command is not recognized. Also not sure if the mkvmerge path is in the right place, as well as the track selection. It seems that the files are properly selected though, so the loop is definitely working as it should.

Comment: You replace the line ```Echo matching suffixed filename to "%%~I%%~xG" is "%%~G"``` with your `mkvmerge` command line.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip ! I managed to make it work ! Here is the full code that I'v entered : https://codefile.io/f/7rjeZJ8tkv

I was trying to replace it by my own command line, however I only had to use the MKVToolNix command line, as the 'do' was actually already there. So I took that line, replaced the file names by "%%~I%%~xG" and "%%~G" accordingly, and it has worked perfectly ! Thank you so much for the help, there are hundreds of files to work with, that's a big spine out of my foot. I hope this helps others too.